# Does Mac X11 have the XTEST extension?

Tags: macos, x11

So I moved some X programs down to the mac, and I'm getting

```
Error: XTEST extension unavailable on '(null)'.
```

from xdotool.

- Does OS X X11 come with XTEST?
- If not, is there a way to add it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Run the following command in the Terminal:

```
defaults write org.x.X11 enable_test_extensions -boolean true
```

(as per [here](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki/X112.3.2)).  Then quit and restart the X server; the XTEST extension should then be available.

Comment: Splendid, thanks!  I can't imagine why that's not set be default.

Comment: Automating input may be seen as a security risk, especially since XTEST doesn't set the `send_event` flag in the `XEvent` structure which lets the application know it's being automated.

Comment: FYI what the link was pointing to in this answer has been moved.

Comment: No luck on Mac 10.15.7, XQuartz 2.8.1 (xorg-server 1.20.11)

Comment: I'm on macOS 11.4, and this does not seem to do anything.  Running `xdpyinfo` I can see that XTEST is not listed under the 'number of extensions' section.  ...

Answer (score 8):

I had to do the following two commands to get this to work on Mountain Lion (from [here](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/ticket/526)):

```
defaults write org.x.X11 enable_test_extensions -boolean true
defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 enable_test_extensions -boolean true
```

Comment: Neither one helped on Mac 10.15.7, XQuartz 2.8.1 (xorg-server 1.20.11)

Comment: `defaults write org.xquartz.X11 enable_test_extensions -bool yes` seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 4):

For XQuartz,

```
defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 enable_test_extensions -bool yes
```

See [this link](https://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/ticket/414).

Answer (score 2):

Mac has test extension as part of the open source [XQuartz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XQuartz) project (if installed).

The X11.app was available by default for Mac OS X v10.5-10.7, but since Mountain Lion, Apple dropped dedicated support for X11.app, with users directed to the open source XQuartz project (to which it contributes) instead.

To test if the TEST extension is enabled, try the following commands:

```
$ defaults read org.x.X11
{
    "enable_test_extensions" = 1;
}
$ defaults read org.macosforge.xquartz.X11
{
...
    "enable_test_extensions" = 1;
    "startx_script" = "/opt/X11/bin/startx -- /opt/X11/bin/Xquartz";
}
```

For downloading instructions, check [XQuartz page](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/).